# QFileSystemModel, QTableView и виджеты на представлении

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется задача на одном представлении, в одной строке с файлом из QFileSystemModel отображать некий виджет (скажем, QPushButton). Какие есть для этого пути?

Если ничего не трогать, и привязать модель к представлению, получаем 4 столбца, из которых нужно только имя (еще один, для виджета, нужно создать)

Сейчас рассматриваю варианты, но в силу неопытности, не могу оценить приемущества или недостатки того или иного подхода.

Comment: Наследовать QStyledItemWidget, в котором отображать кнопку во втором столбце (кстати, для чего там она?). Также наследовать QFileSystemModel, чтобы из метода data возвращать нужные данные для кнопок. Надо бы побольше информации

Comment: Кнопка и кнопка, скажем, чтоб копировать в буфер полный путь к фалу, или QComboBox для задания некоего статуса директории. Короче, виджет. Если наследовать QFileSystemModel и там переопределять data(), то, я так понимаю, нужно еще и менять columnCount() и headerData. Условный виджет (пусть будет кнопка) для всех строк одинаков

Comment: 1. Просто активация этого виджета будет через двойной клик, либо один, но для выделенной строки. 2. Остальные методы наследуются по вашему желанию и требованиям